# org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table and view not found

Tags: java, apache-spark, neo4j

I am fetching neo4j data into spark dataframe using [neo4j-spark connector](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-spark-connector). I am able to fetch it successfully as I am able to show the dataframe. Then I register the dataframe with [createOrReplaceTempView()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#createOrReplaceTempView(java.lang.String)) method. Then I try running spark sql on it, but it gives exception saying

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: neo4jtable;
```

This is how my whole code looks like:

```
import java.text.ParseException;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.neo4j.spark.Neo4JavaSparkContext;
import org.neo4j.spark.Neo4j;

import scala.collection.immutable.HashMap;

public class Neo4jDF {

    private static Neo4JavaSparkContext neo4jjsc;
    private static SparkConf sConf;
    private static JavaSparkContext jsc;
    private static SparkContext sc; 
    private static SparkSession ss;

    private static Dataset<Row> neo4jdf;
    static String neo4jip = "ll.mm.nn.oo";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AnalysisException, ParseException 
    {
        setSparkConf();
        setJavaSparkContext();
        setNeo4jJavaSparkContext();
        setSparkContext();
        setSparkSession();

        neo4jdf = loadNeo4jDataframe();
        neo4jdf.createOrReplaceTempView("neo4jtable");

        neo4jdf.show(false); //this prints correctly

        Dataset<Row> neo4jdfsqled = ss.sql("SELECT * from neo4jtable");

        neo4jdfsqled.show(false); //this throws exception
    }

    private static Dataset<Row> loadNeo4jDataframe(String pAutosysBoxCaption)
    {
        Neo4j neo4j = new Neo4j(jsc.sc());
        HashMap<String, Object> a = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        Dataset<Row> rdd = neo4j.cypher("cypher query deleted for irrelevance", a).loadDataFrame();
        return rdd;
    }

    private static void setSparkConf()
    {
        sConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("GetNeo4jToRddDemo");
        sConf.set("spark.neo4j.bolt.url", "bolt://" + neo4jip + ":7687");
        sConf.set("spark.neo4j.bolt.user", "neo4j");
        sConf.set("spark.neo4j.bolt.password", "admin");
        sConf.setMaster("local");
        sConf.set("spark.testing.memory", "471859200");
        sConf.set("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///D:/Mahesh/workspaces/spark-warehouse");
    }

    private static void setJavaSparkContext()
    {
        jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sConf);
    }

    private static void setSparkContext()
    {
        sc = JavaSparkContext.toSparkContext(jsc);
    }

    private static void setSparkSession()
    {
        ss = new SparkSession(sc);
    }

    private static void setNeo4jJavaSparkContext()
    {
        neo4jjsc = Neo4JavaSparkContext.neo4jContext(jsc);
    }
}
```

I feel the issue might be with how all spark environment variables are created.
I first created `SparkConf sConf`.
From `sConf`, I created `JavaSparkContext jsc`.
From `jsc`, I created `SparkContext sc`.
From `sc`, I created `SparkSession ss`.
From `ss`, I created Neo4jJavaSparkContext `neo4jjjsc`.

So visually:

```
sConf -> jsc -> sc       -> ss 
             -> neo4jjsc
```

Also note that

- Inside loadNeo4jDataframe(), I use `sc` to instantiate instance `Neo4j neo4j`, which is then used for fetching neo4j data.
- Data is fetched using `Neo4j` instance.
- `neo4jjjsc` is never used, but I kept it as a possible hint for issue.

Given all these points and observations, please tell me why I get table not found exception? I must be missing something stupid. :\

**Update**

Tried setting `ss` (after data is fetched using SparkContext of neo4j) as follows:

```
private static void setSparkSession(SparkContext sc)
{
    ss = new SparkSession(sc);
}

private static Dataset<Row> loadNeo4jDataframe(String pAutosysBoxCaption)
{
    Neo4j neo4j = new Neo4j(sc);

    Dataset<Row> rdd = neo4j.cypher("deleted cypher for irrelevance", a).loadDataFrame();

    //initalizing ss after data is fetched using SparkContext of neo4j
    setSparkSession(neo4j.sc());  
    return rdd;
}
```

**Update 2**

From comments, just realised that `neo4j` creates a its own spark session using spark context `sc` instance provided to it. I am not having access to that spark session. So, how I am supposed to add / register arbitrary dataframe (here, `neo4jdf`) which is created in some other spark session (here spark session created by `neo4j.cypher`) to my spark session `ss`?

Comment: If this is reproducible, then most likely `neo4j.cypher(...).loadDataFrame` doesn't use the same session as your main code.

Comment: but `neo4j` instance is instantiated using same `SparkContext` using which I created `SparkSession`. Also I tried initializing `ss` as `ss = new SparkSession(neo4j.sc())` after data was fetched. But it still did not work. Please check the update.

Comment: `SparkSession` (or `SQLContext`) not `SparkContext`. Spark application can have multiple sessions / SQL contexts, and Neo connector clearly initializes some by default.

Comment: ohhhh...so `neo4j` creates a its own spark session using spark context `sc` instance provided to it. I am not having access to that spark session. So, how I am supposed to add / register arbitrary dataframe to my spark session `ss`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the symptoms we can infer that both pieces of code use different `SparkSession`  / `SQLContext`. Assuming there is nothing unusual going on in the Neo4j connector, you should be able to fix this by changing:

```
private static void setSparkSession()
{
    ss = SparkSession().builder.getOrCreate();
}
```

or by initializing `SparkSession` before calling `setNeo4jJavaSparkContext`.

If these won't work, you can switch to using `createGlobalTempView`.

**Important**:

In general I would recommend initializing single `SparkSession` using builder pattern, and deriving other contexts (`SparkContexts`) from it, when necessary.

Comment: I remember I read about `createGlobalTempView`, but it did not clicked me...lack of experience may be...also that `SparkSession().builder.getOrCreate()` was perfect!!!